# Data structure alignment difference in Go and C

Tags: c, go, data-structures, shared-memory

I have initialized a structure inside my C program and attached it to the Shared memory. The structure is as below:

```c
#define DrvMaxTag 1024
#define DrvMaxStr 128
#define StructLEN 32

typedef struct TagTypeStruct
{
    unsigned char IO;
    unsigned char Drv;
    unsigned char Class;
    unsigned char Group;
}TagTypeStruct;

typedef struct IEC_DT
{
    long int tv_Sec;
    long int tv_nSec;
}IEC_DT;

typedef struct DrvSHMTagStruct
{
    char          TagName[DrvMaxTag][DrvMaxStr];
    double        TagValue[DrvMaxTag];
    double        OldValue[DrvMaxTag];
    unsigned int  TagStatus[DrvMaxTag];
    unsigned int  OldStatus[DrvMaxTag];
    long long     TagControl[DrvMaxTag];
    IEC_DT        TagValueDT[DrvMaxTag];
    TagTypeStruct TagType[DrvMaxTag];
    int           DrvAddr[DrvMaxTag];
    unsigned char LogFlag[DrvMaxTag];
    unsigned char Freeze[DrvMaxTag];
    int           LogicState;
    char          DrvPath[DrvMaxStr];
    int           TagQuantity;
    unsigned char Instance;
}DrvSHMTagStruct;
```

I'm trying to read the structure from another program that is written in Golang. I have calculated how many bytes each field takes in C and have an equivalent field for it inside my Golang structure which is as below:

```golang
const StructLEN = 32
const DrvMaxTag = 1024
const DrvMaxStr = 128

type TagTypeStruct struct {
    IO    uint8
    Drv   uint8
    Class uint8
    Group uint8
}

type IEC_DT struct {
    tv_Sec  int32
    tv_nSec int32
}

type DrvSHMTagStruct struct {
    TagName [DrvMaxTag][DrvMaxStr]byte
    TagValue   [DrvMaxTag]float64
    OldValue   [DrvMaxTag]float64
    TagStatus  [DrvMaxTag]uint32
    OldStatus  [DrvMaxTag]uint32
    TagControl [DrvMaxTag]int64
    TagValueDT [DrvMaxTag]IEC_DT
    TagType    [DrvMaxTag]TagTypeStruct
    DrvAddr    [DrvMaxTag]int32
    RetainFlag [DrvMaxTag]uint8
    Freeze     [DrvMaxTag]uint8
    LogicState int32
    DrvPath     [DrvMaxStr]uint8
    TagQuantity int32
    Instance    uint8
}
```

The size of the structure (`DrvSHMTagStruct`) in C is **182416** and in Golang is **182412** (my OS is ARM-based). So why the difference? They are different in 4 bytes and the interesting part is that they are both working perfectly, reading and writing on the same structure without a mistake.

As I obviously searched about it, I understood that the C compiler does some [Data Structure alignment](https://geeksforgeeks.org/data-structure-alignment-how-data-is-arranged-and-accessed-in-computer-memory/) during the compilation process. Hence, the 4 bytes difference. But the question is how does the Golang program read the structure from the shared memory correctly even though it has a 4-byte difference?

Also, the problem emerges when I run the programs on my ARM-based Linux. They are the same size when on a x64 Ubuntu.

Comment: **182 KiB**-sized struct? ..._yikes_ Why are you using this approach - of `1024`-sized inline arrays for almost every member?

Comment: Why aren't you using types with a fixed number of bits in C too? `uint32_t` instead of `unsigned int` and `int64_t` instead of `long long` etc.

Comment: @Dai One thing that I forgot to say is that the C program was written by someone else long ago and it cannot be changed. I'm handling the Go program. So I have no choice but to do the same.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I cannot edit the C program because it is already in production. Also, they are working correctly. My question is, why do they have a 4-byte difference?

Comment: @techerfan Most probably because of alignment issues. Print the offset of each member and you'll probably see where the 4 mystery bytes appear.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Did that already. The crazy thing is that it doesn't depend on a specific member. It happens when a combination of members exists in the structure.

Comment: What does `_Alignof(int)`  say on the ARM based system? 4 or 8?  What is `CHAR_BIT` on that system?

Comment: @TedLyngmo it is 4. and the _CHAR_BIT_ is 8.

Comment: Ok, then I think I got it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the padding of the last member, `Instance`. In your C version, it gets padded with 7 bytes. In the Go version it gets padded with 3. The difference is the 4 bytes you notice when doing `sizeof` on the two platforms.

In order to make them the same, you can possibly `#pragma pack(4)` in the the C version or `#pragma pack(8)` in the Go version (if it even supports packing, a search suggests that it doesn't) or add a filler as a last member to the Go struct:

```
Filler1     [7]uint8
```

Comment: That's true. Thanks! Another question is that I have initialized a 32-length array of that struct in the shared memory and even without that `Filter1` member in my Go struct, I'm reading the values correctly. So even though each item in the array has a 4-byte difference, the order is still right and the values are correct. why??

Comment: @techerfan There's no 4 byte difference. It's just padding after the last member. If you made an array of `DrvSHMTagStruct` and tried to access members is the second array, then you would have an offset mismatch